# Codename One override Android onNewIntent activity method

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nfc, codenameone

I found a lot of Android examples that override the main Activity lifecycle methods like `onResume`, `onPause`, etc. with Codename One. I am accessing Android native code through an interface class.

Now I would like to also override the method `onNewIntent`. How can I accomplish that? Is it even possible? Do I need to pass through C1 methods like `public void start()` and `public void stop()`?

I have activated NFC on the mobile phone and when my NFC card is held to the phone I would like to catch that NFC intent. This intent is sent to the app through `onNewIntent`.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a completely separate activity that is totally unrelated to Codename One and place it in the native/android hierarchy. You can register it in the manifest XML using something like the `android.xactivity` [build hint](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html).

From this point on it just becomes a native activity that can communicate back to Codename One.

Notice that if you want Codename One code to respond to onResume you can just write it in the `start()` method which is invoked when the application is restarted.

Comment: that would be perfect. If i create a new Class in the native/android/com/mycompany/myapp  path, the file disappears and goes inside the Source Packages along with the theme.res, i don't think it's ok. So, what i need to do? And after that, i want to make it my main activity. I should make it start from an interface class from C1?

Comment: Disappears in the IDE? I'm assuming you mean in the compiled app? That's perfectly fine for an Android build because it's meant to be a part of the sources but only for Android targeted builds. If you will send an iOS targeted build the file will be completely ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you modify the Codename One framework (or specifically its Android implementation), there is not much you can do to receive the `onNewIntent()` callback. The current implementation of the [`LifecycleListener`](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/v3.3/Ports/Android/src/com/codename1/impl/android/LifecycleListener.java) does not support the `onNewIntent()` lifecycle method. Also the only thing that Codename One does when the `onNewIntent()` callback fires is to store the new intent as the current activity intent (see [CodenameOneActivity.java:367](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/v3.3/Ports/Android/src/com/codename1/impl/android/CodenameOneActivity.java#L367)):

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

So if you need to get a notification when `onNewIntent()` fires, the only way would be to modify the Codename One framework.

However, there is something that you can do: Use the `onResume()` lifecycle method instead. This method is guaranteed to be invoked after `onNewIntent()`, and since the current activity intent is updated using `setIntent(...)` you can grab that intent once your app is notified about `onResume()`.

1. You would first create a lifecylce listener object and register it using the `AndroidNativeUtil` class:

   ```
   LifecycleListener listener = new LifecycleListener() {
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {}
       public void onPause() {}
       public void onDestroy() {}
       public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b) {}
       public void onLowMemory() {}

       public void onResume() {
           // this is where you get notified about onResume()
       }
   };

   AndroidNativeUtil.addLifecycleListener(listener);
   ```
2. You would then retrieve the intent in the `onResume` listener:

   ```
   public void onResume() {
       Activity myActivity = AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity();
       Intent potentialNfcIntent = myActivity.getIntent();

       // do something with the intent if its an NFC intent
   }
   ```
3. Since the invokation of `onNewIntent()` is not the only reason why `onResume()` may be called (in fact there are many other reasons this may happen), you might want to implement some checking that you process that specific intent only once.

Comment: Ok, the `onResume()`method works perfectly. The problem now is `onCreate()`. I put an alert inside both of them, when i start the App nothing happen, after i resume the App i get the Resume alert and then Create alert. Why? I also don't understand why I don't catch the Create alert in the first place...

Comment: @Giuliano Looking at the Codename One Android implementation I'm not sure why this would happen. Could it be that you register the LifecycleListener in or after CN1 `start()` is invoked?

Comment: Maybe it's a thread problem about the alerts, i used them because i don't know how to debug inside the listener. Anyway my main problem is that the first time i launch the app i don't get any alert, but after i pause the app and then resume it, i get the alert and the app works as i want. So, it seems the listener can't get the first `onCreate` and `onResume`, and i need to catch `onResume`, to do the `enableForegroundDispatch()`. I also tried to initiliaze the listener in the `init()` of C1 but it's always the same. Probably because the activity is already created?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I made it working. I used the `LifecycleListener()` solution. This is how I did it: in my interface class I create a static method to create my LifecycleListener and do `AndroidNativeUtil.addLifecycleListener(myListener);`. I call this static method from the built hints of the app with `android.onCreate=com.mycompany.myapp.MyNativeImpl.start();`. When i start my app, the alert i put in the `onResume()` method pops up. Perfect.

There is another approach, using the init/start/stop of C1, but i couldn't manage to make it work. I got null pointer on the nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispactch(...), i don't know why, because i check if the adapter and every parameter wasn't null before using the method. 
Maybe it's `PendingIntent` problem? This is how i wrote it:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().getClass());
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question right, you  want to a common place to handle newIntent method of different activities.

If so, then define a custom activity and make other activities extend it.

```
public class CustomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        // put your code here
    }
}

public class SomeActivity extends CustomActivity {

}
```

Comment: You are very close to what i am meaning. My problem is that when i get access to the android native part, i think Codename One access through the main activity, but i don't have access to modify it and override it. I have found the AndroidUtilNative.addLifecycleListener class, maybe that's what i am looking for.